# Python output different in Sublime vs PyCharm

Tags: python

I get different results when I run the following code in Sublime Text 3 versus PyCharm:

```
message = input('type a message: ')
words = message.split(' ')
print(words)
```

They both prompt me to type a message, but Sublime text doesn't print out a list with the words of my message while PyCharm does. (I'm running Python 3.7.4)

Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it sill not work if you use: ```for word in words: print(word)``` ?

Comment: Does not work in Sublime, but does work in PyCharm. That outputs:
this
is
my
message

Comment: Can you print anything to the console when using Sublime?

Comment: @AMC I sure can! When I hit COMMAND+B, I can print, just not with this group of lines. I'm a little spooked here because I've tried a few Python lessons, and there are some things where Sublime has been inconsistent with PyCharm. I'm worried that I goofed a setting or something :/

Comment: @chet_nightstick That's really bizarre. What happens if you insert a print statement right before and one right after the `print(words)` ?

Comment: @AMC I tried this:

message = input('type a message: ')
words = message.split(' ')
print('start')
print(words)
print('end')

It prompts me to type the message. I do that, hit return, and the cursor moves to the next line and just blinks at me (condescendingly)!

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems that the way the default Sublime Text build system works means that you cannot pass input to your program during execution. See: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-broken-python-3-input/44988/3. How are you running your program?

Comment: @AMC I've since switched to using IDLE and am having a much better experience lol. Thank you for your help!